# How to create a calculated column that computes the non-null value from one of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a new database that requires a calculated column that pulls a percentage from one column (`GrossMarginPercentage`) and multiplies it by either an estimated value or an actual value column. Only one will contain a value and the other will be null.

Would any functions help me tell the new computed column what column (estimated or actual) to pull from and multiply by `GrossMarginPercentage`?

I tried:

```
Alter Table ChurnInfo

add DecMargin as case (when DecEstimated = 'Null' then 

DecActual * GrossMarginPercentage else DecEst*GrossMarginPercentage end )
```

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657223/11073192

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
Alter Table ChurnInfo
    add DecMargin as (coalesce(DecActual, DecEst) * GrossMarginPercentage);
```

Comment: This did indeed work but the new column is only displaying NULL. Is this potentially a result of datatypes not working together?

Comment: @Jman No - it is because both of the 2 columns in the coalesce function are null or the other (GrossMarginPercentage) is null.